# Can I Automate pester Tests in Azure test plans?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, automated-tests, pester

So I am new to Azure Test plans and created few test cases.
I wanted to link/associate my tests (written using pester) with the test cases in azure test plans.
I saw many tutorials but it's all about Visual studio and c# tests - how to associate automated tests in test plans.

and my requirement is :
associate my pester tests with azure test cases.
is it possible?

Comment: I would like further assistance @YujunDing-MSFT

Comment: You can try to integrate PowerShell code with your .NET project,  in that case, it might be possible to associate https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/introduction/installation#nuget

Comment: What kind of pester solution do you have?

Answer (score 1):

These are the limitations for each type of test are supported for Azure Assosiation:

- Coded UI test, Selenium tests, and unit tests written using Version 1
  of the MSTest framework can be associated with a test case.
- Tests that use MSTest v2, NUnit, and xUnit frameworks can be
  associated with a test case workitem when using Visual Studio 15.9
  Preview 2 or later. However, these tests cannot be run using
  Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
- Tests that use the .NET core framework can be associated with a test
  case workitem when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. To
  run the .NET core tests the appropriate target framework must be
  specified in a runsettings file. However, these tests cannot be run
  using Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
- Tests that use other test frameworks such as Chutzpah (for JavaScript
  tests such as Mocha or QUnit), or Jest cannot be associated with a
  test case.
- Associating generic tests may work, but running these tests is not
  supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops#test-types

Comment: so it is not possible in the case of pester solutions? @lia

Comment: What kind of pester solution do you have? If it's a part of .NET project then you can try. The answer above covers all cases.

Comment: It is a monitoring project - has BDD, Gherkin, and pester. Has tests in .tests.ps1 files. It is not a part of .NET project and also doesn't have any .sln file.